# ARIMA models : plot_diagnostics share error

Tags: statsmodels

I am using plot_diagnostics to plot the ARIMA model.

My code is

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                            order=(1, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)
results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

So far everything is good. 
But when I try to use plot_diagonistic, I got error.

```
results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(30,15))
plt.show()
```

The error is

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (3,) (9,)
```

Not sure why this happened. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the lags value in plot_diagnostic, see example below :

```
results.plot_diagnostics(**lags=4**,figsize=(30,15))
```

While changing the lags value keep an eye on your error message parameters :

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with **shapes
>   (9,) (3,) (9,)**

message could change, So accordingly you can adjust your lags value and resolve the error.